# Does UUID.randomUUID() contain any special characters?

Tags: java

ok, see

```
String myUniversalString=String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID());
```

My question is that

Does `myUniversalString` contain any special characters such as `"#","@","!","~", etc`?

Comment: I don't know, you tell us. What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 10):

Only hyphens (`-`). The format of the returned string is documented in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString()).